# Why isn't a function calling itself in its body considered recursive (vs iterative)?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am learning Scheme/Racket and am confused with recursion-vs-iteration concept.

The specific question is: Write a function that sums up a list of numbers.

Take the following code, for example:

```
(define (func list)
  (define (dostuff list res)
    (if (empty? list)
        res
        (dostuff (cdr list) (+ (car list) res))))
  (dostuff list 0))
```

According to the instructor, this is a iterative solution. But I don't understand why. `dostuff` is calling itself within its implementation, so doesn't that automatically make it recursive?

Or am I missing some concept here?

Comment: Yes, that function *is* recursive. The confusion you’re experiencing likely stems from sort of confusing terms: there are two common *patterns* of recursion, one of which is referred to as “iterative”. Of course, in many functional programming languages, including Scheme, there is no built-in “iteration” construct, only recursion. However, the two are actually equivalent in power: you can implement iteration in terms of recursion and vice-versa.

Comment: SICP (and by extension many Scheme programmers) distinguishes between a procedure and the *process* it generates. [Chapter 1.2](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2) explains it pretty well. (This distiction makes more sense in Scheme than in most other languages, as tail-call elimination is a required feature of Scheme implementations.)

Comment: @AlexisKing what do you mean by power here. Is it expressive power, computational power, or something else? (I say that because I don't actually think iteration is as expressive as recursion. Giving the Acumen function as an example.)

Comment: (But I do completely agree they share the same computational power.)

Comment: it is recursive syntactically and iterative procedurally. Recursive process uses up more and more stack space; iterative process runs in constant stack space, whether the code describing it is syntactically recursive or not.

Answer (score 4):

It's "iterative" because it's tail-recursive. That is, it recurses only in tail position (i.e., the code returns to the caller immediately after the recursion, with no other work, so it's safe to just replace the current call frame with the recursive call's).

In languages like Scheme, which enforces "proper tail calls", tail recursion is effectively a goto. As Alexis's comment says, in Scheme, loops are written using tail recursion, since Scheme does not have a goto.

Comment: there's also [`do`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.4).

Comment: @WillNess There is `do`, but a standard implementation of the `do` macro is to expand into a named `let` that calls itself via tail recursion. :-)

Comment: where it states so? or did you mean "usual" and not "standard"?

Comment: @WillNess The standard suggested implementation of `do` (at the bottom of section 7.3, in the case of R5RS) does use tail recursion. It doesn't specifically use a named `let`, though what it does have can, of course, very easily be written as a named `let`.

Comment: however it's implemented, `do` is in the language,  and so in Scheme loops can be written using `do` as well.

Comment: @WillNess Correct. I still conceptually consider that a tail-recursive approach.

Comment: but when we say "written" we refer to the code *as written*, syntax-wise. Not concepts-wise. :) Otherwise, we could say we write Scheme with `goto`s. Because tail call under TCO *is* a `goto`. But nevermind that.

Comment: @WillNess If we're talking about code-as-written, then I could extend your point to say that code using `foldr` does not recurse, syntax-wise, and that code using `foldl` does not tail-recurse, syntax-wise. But that seems like BS, because behind the scenes, it's obvious what actually happens.

Comment: Precisely, it *isn't* recursive, syntactically. It uses a higher order function which captures a recursive pattern, one TR, the other not. By using `fold` we free ourselves from having to use recursion explicitly; we're one step above it. The correct pattern of recursion is guaranteed, taken care of, by thinking in terms of a specific HOF.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the [MIT 6.001 lecture 1B of Structure and Interpretations](https://youtu.be/dlbMuv-jix8?list=PLE18841CABEA24090&t=1144) whose the Prof.  Gerald Jay Sussman made a graceful explanation about the differences of `iteration vs recursion` using Scheme (LISP-1).

The biggest difference behind that types of algorithms is linked with the concept of *memory* and *space*. Iterative procedures doesn't need know what happened on the previously statements. However, recursive procedures yes.

Think a little about each these algorithms for add:

```
;; iterative
(define (+ x y)
    (if (= x 0)
         y
        (+ (1- x) (1+ y))))

;; recursive
(define (+ x y)
    (if (= x 0)
         y
         (1+ (+ (1- x) y))))
```

All them do the same things, but the way of the procedures are executed are different.

If you expand the execution for the first using `(+ 3 4)` we have that flow:

```
(+ 3 4)
(+ 2 5)
(+ 1 6)
(+ 0 7)
7
```

Time=`O(n)`, space=`O(1)`

However, for the second, see:

```
(+ 3 4)
(1+ (+ 2 4))
(1+ (1+ (+ 1 4)))
(1+ (1+ (1+ (+ 0 4))))
(1+ (1+ (1+ 4)))
(1+ (1+ 5))
(1+ 6)
7
```

time=`O(n)`, space=`O(n)`

Comment: ... differences between iterative and recursive *processes* ... A procedure can be recursive and still invoke an iterative process. +1 for showing the evolved process of each procedure

Comment: Thanks for that point! You are correct. I would want mean *procedure* instead *process*. I'll edit.